# Sorting two combined data.frames

Tags: r, sorting, date, dataframe

I have two data.frames with a common column `dates` that I construct by dropping time from original timestamps.  I want to combine both data.frames and sort the result upon dates:

```
tbl <- rbind(tabf, tabi)
tblo <- tbl[order(dates), ]
```

The problem is that `dates` has the nrow of the 2nd data.frame, and the result of sorting has that nrow, not nrow of combined data.frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another object named `dates` in your environment if this isn't returning the message: `error: object "dates" not found`. Specify that it's the column `dates` inside of `tbl`:

```
tblo <- tbl[order(tbl$dates),]
```

And don't be afraid to use spaces in your code! You'll run into problems with things like `2<-3` vs. `2 < -3`